# JavaScript grade, average and status calculator

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to implement a simple program that asks the user to enter his marks(1-100), then outputs the grade, average and status.

As you can see, here is an example of it.

(In HTML)

I created five boxes, one for marks input which is between 1-100, other for subjects input, which is between 1-10 subjects, and the remaining boxes to display the output such as grade, average and status.

(In JS)

I created three variables, one to hold the marks and others to hold subjects and average.

(As you can see, this is just an example I can't put the whole code here)

Then I used if and else to calculate it, and as showed here if the marks are above or equal to 95 and not less or equal to 0, it displays a grade value `A+` and average(marks entered divided by subjects entered), and status `You Passed`.
else it displays wrong info.

But it's not working guys! So please, if you can help I will appreciate it.

And Thanks in advance!

JS:

```
function Calculate() {
  var marks = document.getElementById('marks').value;
  var subjects = document.getElementById('subjects').value;
  var avarage = marks / subjects;
  if (marks >= 95 && marks != 0) {
    document.getElementById('garde').value = "A+";
    document.getElementById('avarage').value = avarage;
    document.getElementById('state').value = "You Passed";
  } else {
    alert("Wrong Info")
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>GPA</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Please Enter Your Marks(1-100)</label>
  <input type="number" id="marks">
  <label>How Many Subjects Were You Taking(1-10)</label>
  <input type="number" id="subjects">
  <br><br>
  <label>Your Grade Is :</label>
  <input type="text" id="grade">
  <label>Your Avarage Is :</label>
  <input type="text" id="avarage">
  <label>You :</label>
  <input type="text" id="state">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` attribute is mismatched, should be `grade` not `garde` like the following:

```
document.getElementById('grade').value = "A+";
```

Comment: A quick debug with the help of chromes developer console would fix this

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].